# biplot in R labeling by two variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pca, biplot, factoextra

Hello I have a multivariate dataset

I performed a PCA over my scaled data and used `fviz_pca_biplot()` function for displaying a biplot.

this is a example of what I did:

(example with mtcars)

```
colnames(mtcars)
```

> "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"

```
ds <- mtcars %>%
  scale()
PCA_analysis <- princomp(ds)
fviz_pca_biplot(PCA_analysis, label = "all", habillage =  mtcars$gear)
```

[image: pca_mtcars]

The issue is that I want to display the labeling not only by "gear" variable but by "am" variable of mtcars dataset, **in a way that the point colors are relative to "gear" variable and the shape of the points are relative of the "am" variable**

Answer (score 2):

No easy way to do it, but you can try only plotting the text:

```
g = fviz_pca_biplot(PCA_analysis, label = "all", 
habillage =  mtcars$gear,geom="text",show.legend=FALSE)
```

Then you add the data manually to the ggplot object and complete by calling geom_point() :

```
g$data$am = factor(mtcars$am)
g$data$gear = factor(mtcars$gear)
g + geom_point(aes(color = gear,shape = am))
```

[image]